# Create an environment like the `checkboxes` in exam.cls

Tags: macros, environments, boxes, exam

I am having trouble on how will i create something like the `checkboxes`or `oneparcheckboxes` environment in `exam.cls`. The only difference is that since the `checkboxes` gives circle, i'd like to create environment which give squarebox for multiple choice.

when i type this in `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question How should I?
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice AA \choice BB \choice CC
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

it would output a vertical lane of choices like

[image]

and using `oneparcheckboxes` environment:

```
 \begin{onecheckboxes}
 \choice AA \choice BB \choice CC
 \end{onecheckboxes}
```

[image]

i would like to create something like the `checkboxes` and `oneparcheckboxes`:

[image]

Comment: If using the `exam` class is an option, I'm sure you can redefine the symbol it uses for checkboxes.  Is there a particular reason you want to avoid the class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\checkboxchar{$\square$}`

## Code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\checkboxchar{$\square$}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question How should I?
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice AA \choice BB \choice CC
\end{checkboxes}

\question How should I?
 \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
 \choice AA \choice BB \choice CC
 \end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also like putting `\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}` in the preamble just to keep the aesthetic look.

Comment: alright, im going to try this one. I've seen this one in the commands declared : `\checkedchar{$\surd$}` what does this mean? especially the `\surd`?

Comment: @Kayla Put `\checkedchar{$\surd$}` in the preamble and see yourself `;-)`. It puts a `tick` mark.