# How to use a ballot character instead of a bullet?

Tags: symbols, unicode, itemize

I want to use the ballot box character instead of a bullet in an itemize environment.

1. **How many wives did Henry VIII had?**

   ☐ 3

   ☐ 6

   ☐ 8

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Itemize with a dash “-” instead of a bullet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62496/5764)

Comment: You can use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and specify the `label` as `☐` or `$\square$`. To find an appropriate symbol, see [How to look up a symbol?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100002/create-an-environment-like-the-checkboxes-in-exam-cls

Comment: I was aware of how to change the item bullet, not how to get the box though. I though that this way the question seemed more broad. @Werner Thanks for the link to the symbols table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example (last item without changes)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}

\def\Item{\item[$\Box$]}

\begin{itemize}
\Item
A
\Item 
B
\item
C
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]